# return type for event in TinyOS

Tags: tinyos, nesc

I'm implementing a module using `nesC` for `TinyOS`. My modules uses interface Timer<> so I have to implement the event fired of the interface Timer, it is possible to return a value inside this implementation or an event must be always void?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of the `Timer.fired` event is defined as `void` and this cannot be changed. Even if the type was non-void, the returned value would be delivered to the component that signals the event, which is some system component implementing the `Timer` interface.

In order to get some hints on how to solve your problem, please provide more details explaining for what purpose you want to return a value from the `fired` event, that is, who is expected to get and process the returned value.